# Should I pass Model object to multiple Services within a Controller in Spring application

Tags: spring, service, model, transactions, controller

I have a scenario, inside of my Controller, I want to call Service A to do something and get an object returned, then call to Service B to do something and get another object returned.

Controller -> (Service A return Object A, then Service B return Object B) -> Object A set to Model object and Object B set to Model as well.

Using this approach, the transaction won't be supported if I put the Transactional in the service A and Service B,  I know it's not recommended to put Transactional at the Controller layer.  So another approach is to create Service C as below:

Controller -> Service C -> Service A return Object A, then Service B return Object B -> Combine Object A and Object B into Object C, return to Controller -> put Object C into Model object.

I really don't like this approach since I have to combine Object A and Object B into Object C just because I need both Objects (A and B) in the Model, from the logical perspective, It doesn't make sense to combine both Objects, especially if I have more Services to call, I would have to combine more returned Objects into single meaningless Object.  Using HashMap could be another approach to avoid creating the Object C, however the controller would have to parse Hashmap and copy the items into Model.

So, seems like the easiest way is to pass the Model object to Service C so that Service C could add Object A and Object B to Model directly.  But I know it's bad practice since Service layer should not interact with Model which should be the job of Controller.

I'm really struggling on this, hope someone could give me a direction.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: But what is reason for _Using this approach, the transaction won't be supported if I put the Transactional in the service A and Service B_ ? Maybe you should better fix the transactional issue, then?